# Equivalent subbases for the weak operator topology on $B(H)$?

Tags: general-topology, operator-theory

Looking at two different textbooks, I see two different definitions for a subbase of the weak operator topology. From Davidson's *$C^*$-algebras by example*:

> The weak operator topology (WOT) on $B(H)$ is defined as the weakest topology such that the sets $\mathcal{W}(T, x, y) := \{ A \in B(H): \lvert \langle(T-A)x, y \rangle \rvert < 1\}$ are open. The sets $\bigcap_{i=1}^n \mathcal{W}(T_i, x_i, y_i)$ form a base for the WOT topology.

From Halmos' *Hilbert Space Problem Book*:

> A subbase for the weak operator topology is the collection of all sets of the form $\{ A \in B(H): \lvert \langle (A-T)x,y \rangle \rvert < \epsilon\}$ where $\epsilon > 0$.

Why is taking sets with $\lvert \langle(T-A)x, y \rangle \rvert < 1$ "enough" to generate the same topology as one where this quantity is less than (arbitrary) $\epsilon$? I've tried playing around a bit but I'm having a bit of a mental block (it's been a while since I took topology).

Edit: typo in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because $x$ and $y$ are varying. $\lvert \langle(T-A)x, y \rangle \rvert < 1$ implies that $\lvert \langle(T-A)x, \epsilon y \rangle \rvert < \epsilon$